# Snapshoting a Persistent Disk (fsfreeze or not?)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've two sets of instructions for snapshoting without unmounting the PD

http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/persistent-disk-backups-using-snapshots.html

```
> sudo sync
> sudo fsfreeze -f /mnt/my-disk
> gcutil addsnapshot --source_disk=my-disk my-snapshot --nosynchronous_mode
```

and

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#creating_snapshots
which just uses sync without fsfreeze

```
> sudo sync
```

I notice that the first set of instructions is a year or so old (and uses the deprecated gcutil), so my question is: is it recommended to use fsfreeze? Or is sync sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to continue using **fsfreeze**. As you can see in the [second link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#creating_snapshots) you provided, one of the steps is:

- Stop your applications from writing to your persistent disk.

With fsfreeze you can achieve that purpose and you shouldn't have any issue creating snapshosts. Therefore I think that the steps are the same in both links but in the second one they are not very clear.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first link is more accurate, fsfreeze is recommended, as well as stopping IOs from your application if possible.

Instructions in the 2nd link have been fixed and will be live shortly.